# ASP.NET MVC 2 paging Route Problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, paging

I get error when paging,

my actions:

```
ProductList(string country, string city, string town, int? pageNumber)
```

my Route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ProductList",
    "myList/{country}/{city}/{town}/{pageNumber}",
    new { controller = "Product", action = "ProductList", country="", city="", town= "", pageNumber = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Action Link:

```
Url.Action("myList","Product", new{ country="Finland",city="",town="",pageNumber=2 })
```

city = 2 ??

I've found a solution as follows:

```
Url.Action("myList","Product", new{ country="Finland",city="s",town="n",pageNumber=2 })
```

http:/myList/Finland/s/n/2

```
ProductList(string country, string city, string town, int? pageNumber)
{
    city== "s" ? city = null;
    town == "n" ? town= null;

    process...
}
```

to be http:
/myList/Finland/2
/myList/Finland/Helsinki/3
/myList/Finland/town/7

Comment: this is __not__ about 'mvc'. maybe about some specific MVC-inspired framework?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot skip the parameters in that route. You just can't call http://mylist/2 and expect pageNumber to take value 2. Value in first segment is assigned to the **first variable in the route**. So 2 is assigned to city variable. You have to make sure all parameters before pageNumber gets a non-null value.

Answer (score 0):

Only the last parameter in your route definition can be optional.